# How can I use consolidate multiple 'scroll' event fns into one for multiple elements w/ diff parameters (that perform the same tasks)?

Tags: javascript, scroll, dom-events, event-listener

I have X elements on a page and each of them does the same thing when they are within a number of viewports from being viewable (say 2x for this example).

Currently, I have a number of logical statements to call each event listener fn.

```
if(!!document.getElementById('foo1'))window.addEventListener('scroll', listenerFoo1);
if(!!document.getElementById('foo2'))window.addEventListener('scroll', listenerFoo2);
if(!!document.getElementById('foo3'))window.addEventListener('scroll', listenerFoo3);
if(!!document.getElementById('foo4'))window.addEventListener('scroll', listenerFoo4);
//etc...
```

Each of these `listenerFooX` functions checks for when the element is within the 2 viewports and then executes code, followed by a `window.removeEventListener` call to end it.

But writing all these basically repeating functions out takes up a lot of space and makes the file feel super bloated. The only thing I've been able to think of is doing something like the following:

```
document.getElementById('foo1').addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    listenerGroupFn('foo1','bar1',var1a,var1b);
});
document.getElementById('foo2').addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        listenerGroupFn('foo2','bar2',var2a,var2b);
    });
//etc...
```

This of course does not work as those listenerGroupFn's never run.

I thought about giving the anonymous function a name `var listenerGroupFn = function() { ... }` but that doesn't help since in the end when I do `removeEventListener` at the end of that, it will cancel all other elements with the event as well.
Since function names are read only, I can't alter the name after I enter the function for each individual event.

I'm stumped about how I can go about this.
Here's the summary:

1. I have dozens of elements that do the same thing (each with different parameters) when they   scroll within X viewports of in view.
2. I have dozens of separate `listenerFoo#` functions for each one that take up a lot of space in my files.
3. I am trying to consolidate this into one function that gets called for each element, but can
   end separately via a scroll `removeEventListener`without ending all of the others which is where I am stuck.

   *page loads, all event listeners activate*

   *scroll*

   foo1 enters view, executes fn and ends event listener, but does not end all other foo2/3/etc events

   *scroll*

   foo2 enters view, executes fn and ends event listener, but does not end all other foo3/4/etc events

**---EDIT---**

**Adding a snippet of the basic concept**

```js
if(!!document.getElementById('foo1'))window.addEventListener('scroll', foo1Scr);
if(!!document.getElementById('foo2'))window.addEventListener('scroll', foo2Scr);
if(!!document.getElementById('foo3'))window.addEventListener('scroll', foo3Scr);
if(!!document.getElementById('foo4'))window.addEventListener('scroll', foo4Scr);
if(!!document.getElementById('foo5'))window.addEventListener('scroll', foo5Scr);
function foo1Scr(){
 if (document.getElementById('foo1').getBoundingClientRect().top <= (window.innerHeight*1.5)){
   //do things
    console.log('1');
    window.removeEventListener('scroll',foo1Scr);
  }
}
function foo2Scr(){
 if (document.getElementById('foo2').getBoundingClientRect().top <= (window.innerHeight*1.5)){
    //do things
    console.log('2');
    window.removeEventListener('scroll',foo2Scr);
  }
}
function foo3Scr(){
 if (document.getElementById('foo3').getBoundingClientRect().top <= (window.innerHeight*1.5)){
    //do things
    console.log('3');
    window.removeEventListener('scroll',foo3Scr);
  }
}
function foo4Scr(){
 if (document.getElementById('foo4').getBoundingClientRect().top <= (window.innerHeight*1.5)){
   //do things
    console.log('4');
    window.removeEventListener('scroll',foo4Scr);
  }
}
function foo5Scr(){
 if (document.getElementById('foo5').getBoundingClientRect().top <= (window.innerHeight*1.5)){
   //do things
    console.log('5');
    window.removeEventListener('scroll',foo5Scr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style='height:1000px;width:200px;background-color:blue;'></div>
<div id='foo1' style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
</div>
<div style='height:1000px;width:200px;background-color:blue;'></div>
<div id='foo2' style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
</div>
<div style='height:1000px;width:200px;background-color:blue;'></div>
<div id='foo3' style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
</div>
<div style='height:1000px;width:200px;background-color:blue;'></div>
<div id='foo4' style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
</div>
<div style='height:1000px;width:200px;background-color:blue;'></div>
<div id='foo5' style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Still not clear about what you want to achieve? Post a runnable script snippet would help.  2. Wonder why you `removeEventListener`? Generally, there're only few cases that you should `removeEventListener`.  3. You can have a generic event listener listen on `scroll` then dispatch a customize event to the relative element(s).  And of cause, all elements just listen to customize event.

Comment: Hi Jack Ting !
I added a snippet to my post of the idea. As you scroll down and it enters view, a number is printed to the console. In my real scenario, each div is actually an ad I'm loading so there are multiple parameters that need to be passed into the function each time it runs for each separate div.

I do the removeEventListener so once the task for each div happens, it no longer is allowed to.

I'm sure there's a better way to go about to this so I'm not doing multiple functions for each div, but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the condition of firing the `appear` event in the loop:

```
fooElms[i].getBoundingClientRect().top <= window.innerHeight*1.5
```

Instead, you could record and break at the block that not yet appear, and continue form it at next `scroll`, otherwise `fooScr()` will fire `appear` event  continuously event blocks had been shown.

Once the condition of firing `appear` event is correct, it not necessary to `removeEventListener`.

OK, Take a look at the code below.

```js
var foos = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5'];
var fooElms = foos.map( function(foo) {
  let elem = document.getElementById(foo);
  elem.addEventListener('appear', fooXScr);
  return elem;
} );

function fooXScr(ev) {
  let elem = ev.currentTarget;
  console.log(elem.id);
  /* Do something according to specific elem.id */
  elem.removeEventListener('appear',fooXScr);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', fooScr);
function fooScr() {
  for (var i=0; i<fooElms.length; i++) {
    if (fooElms[i].getBoundingClientRect().top <= window.innerHeight*1.5) {
      var ev = document.createEvent('Event');
      ev.initEvent('appear', true, true);
      fooElms[i].dispatchEvent(ev);
      // console.log('fire event to elem:' + fooElms[i].id);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div style='height:1000px;width:200px;background-color:blue;'></div>
<div id='foo1' style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
</div>
<div style='height:1000px;width:200px;background-color:blue;'></div>
<div id='foo2' style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
</div>
<div style='height:1000px;width:200px;background-color:blue;'></div>
<div id='foo3' style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
</div>
<div style='height:1000px;width:200px;background-color:blue;'></div>
<div id='foo4' style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
</div>
<div style='height:1000px;width:200px;background-color:blue;'></div>
<div id='foo5' style='width:300px;height:250px;background-color:lightgreen;'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Jack. I guess my main question to start here is about the 'appear' event you are referring to. I've not heard of it before and can't find any mention of in the MDN site (or any other list of event names I could locate)? Do you have any links to where I can read more about it?

Comment: Nope, it's a customized event that can made by your self.  You can create a event (by `document.createEvent('Event')`), then customize it (by `.initEvent()`).  And then dispatch it to the elements you want.  And, of cause you had to listen to such kind of events.